# How do I supply multiple resources to be defined when creating a resource?

Tags: json, api, json-api

See the example here: http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-creating

If I want to specify multiple 'photographers', would I make the 'data' property an array/collection?

example (from the link, above):

```
POST /photos HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": {
    "type": "photos",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Ember Hamster",
      "src": "http://example.com/images/productivity.png"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "photographer": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be an array - see the [example](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents) for Compound Documents.

```
"relationships": {
  "photographers": {
    "data": [
      { "type": "photographers", "id": "5" },
      { "type": "photographers", "id": "12" }
    ]
  }
```

Note that `photographers` is plural.

If you are going to include any actual photographer records they would be in `included`, which is at the top level with `data`.

Comment: excellent. while posting this question, this occurred to me. i've started down that route. Thank you for your answer and confirming i'm doing this The Right Way.